# I have an input box.If i type 5,5 more fields will be added and if i type 6,6 field will be added,and i have to do it using React js

Tags: reactjs

well My question is,I am adding input field dynamically onClicking of a button,But now i have a input box,Where i will put number,And that number of input will be added,suppuse i type 5,so 5 more input will be added so which number i will put same number of input will be added

`const addFormFields = () => {
setFormValues([...formValues, { name: "", email: "" }])
}

`your text`{formValues.map((element, index) => (

Name
<input type="text" name="name" value={element.name || ""} onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)} />
))

<button className="button add" type="button" onClick={() => addFormFields()}>Add`

Comment: Please take the time to learn the tools in the editor, then format your code properly. Also, your title question isn't very clear. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips and examples.

Comment: Use wizard for asking your first questions